# How to configure Cloud Storage for Firebase bucket CORS when using preview channels?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am relying on the [`getBlob`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#getblob) function to download files from Cloud Storage for Firebase directly from the browser. For this to work, I have allowlisted my app's origin in my Cloud Storage bucket. Everything works fine and is as expected.

However, I am also using Firebase Hosting's preview channels, each creating a new, unique origin. In consequence, for the `getBlob` function to work, I need to re-configure CORS for every new preview channel (and remove configurations for obsolete preview channels).

Is there a way to configure CORS of Cloud Storage buckets to automatically allow origins from all preview channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to automatically allowlist all preview channels (without allowlisting all origins. However, something you could do is use the [CORS configuration API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#rest-apis) and the [Firebase Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.channels#Channel) to script automatically adding all channels after each deploy.

How this would work is essentially you would call `ListChannels` on your site, then use the resulting URLs from that list to populate the CORS configuration via the Cloud Storage API.